# Invalidate ASP.Net control from client side

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a `asp:TextBox` which I am performing validation on via jQuery (when a button is pressed I send a `get` request to a web service which returns a bool indicating whether the contents of the `asp:TextBox` are valid).

Additionally I am using the following code to highlight which controls are invalid (using `asp:RequiredFieldValidator`s, etc.) on submit click:

```
var clientValidate = Page_ClientValidate();

if (!clientValidate) {
    for (var i = 0; Page_Validators.length; i++) {
        $('label[for="' + Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate + '"]')
            .css('color', Page_Validators[i].isvalid ? 'black' : 'red');
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can "tell" `Page_ClientValidate` that a control is invalid manually on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

This will work depending on the .NET version:

```
function ValidatePage() {

    if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
        Page_ClientValidate();
    }

    if (Page_IsValid) {
        // do something
        alert('Page is valid!');                
    }
    else {
        // do something else
        alert('Page is not valid!');
    }
}

// To invalidate:

if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
    Page_IsValid = false;
}

// To loop through all the validators

if (typeof (Page_Validators) == 'function') {
    for (var i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
        var validator = Page_Validators[i]; 
        validator.isvalid = true;
        ValidatorUpdateDisplay(validator);
    }
}
```

Here you can find a good article:

http://asknoor.wordpress.com/2013/02/22/handling-asp-page-validators-using-javascript/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though this doesn't allow me to specify which control is invalid.

Comment: My problem is not getting the information which controls are in `Page_Validators`, it is being able to effectively append data to `Page_Validators`.

Comment: Do you mean you want to add controls to the `Page_Validators` or set their status dynamically with Javascript?

Comment: Hi, the latter I think - I want to make it so I can manually set a control to invalid from JavaScript.

Comment: So you can just set the value within the loop, checking which control.